# ExpandoObject, anonymous types and Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic, razor, anonymous-types, expandoobject

I want to use an ExpandoObject as the viewmodel for a Razor view of type `ViewPage<dynamic>`. I get an error when I do this

```
ExpandoObject o = new ExpandoObject();
o.stuff = new { Foo = "bar" };
return View(o);
```

what can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it with the extension method mentioned in this question:

[Dynamic Anonymous type in Razor causes RuntimeBinderException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120317/dynamic-anonymous-type-in-razor-causes-runtimebinderexception)

So your controller code would look like:

```
dynamic o = new ExpandoObject();
o.Stuff = new { Foo = "Bar" }.ToExpando();

return View(o);
```

And then your view:

```
@model dynamic

@Model.Stuff.Bar
```

Comment: this ended up working after all. it didn't work the first time I tried it b/c I was actually doing something like `ctx.Foo.Select(x => new { Foo = "bar" }.ToExpandoObject()).SingleOrDefault()` when I should have been doing `ctx.Foo.Select(x => new { Foo = "bar" }).SingleOrDefault().ToExpandoObject()`

Answer (score 4):

Using the open source [Dynamitey](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey#dynamitey-) (in nuget) you could make a graph of ExpandoObjects with a very [clean syntax](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey/wiki/UsageBuilder);

```
  dynamic Expando = Build<ExpandoObject>.NewObject;

  var o = Expando (
      stuff: Expando(foo:"bar")
  );

  return View(o);
```

Answer (score 1):

I stand corrected, @gram has the right idea. However, this is still one way to modify your concept.

### Edit

You have to give `.stuff` a type since `dynamic` must know what type of object(s) it's dealing with.

`.stuff` becomes *internal* when you set it to an anonymous type, so `@model dynamic` won't help you here

```
ExpandoObject o = new ExpandoObject();
o.stuff = MyTypedObject() { Foo = "bar" };
return View(o);
```

And, of course, the `MyTypedObject`:

```
public class MyTypedObject
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: yep this is pretty much where I ended up before I had asked on here. If I need to make `MyTypedObject`, might as well ditch the dynamic usage and go back to strongly typed viewmodels :\

Comment: @qntmfred I think @gram has the right idea. I tested the code and it seems to do the trick. It's definitely closer to specifically answering your question.

Comment: yep his approach worked. I commented on his answer as well - I was just doing it slightly wrong the first time I tried it

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the type as `dynamic`

```
dynamic o = new ExpandoObject();
o.stuff = new { Foo = "bar" };
return View(o);
```

Go through this excellent [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2009/10/01/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject.aspx) on ExpandoObject

Comment: While this corrects the compile error, how are you able to access `@Model.stuff.Foo` in the view? `dynamic` objects must know the type of object its dealing with.