# Accessing properties of anonymous/dynamic types across dll boundaries gives RuntimeBinderException

Tags: c#, dynamic, expandoobject

In the following sample, *x.propertyX* works fine, whereas *y.propertyX* gives me a **Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException**, complaining 'propertyX' is not defined in 'object'.

The CreateDynamic method in the Program class (shown below) and the one in Class1 (not shown) are exactly the same, but Class1 is in a different project from Program. If I move Class1 into Program's project, everything works fine.

```
class Program
{
    public static object CreateDynamic()
    {
        return new { propertyX = "asdf" };
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic x = CreateDynamic();
        Console.WriteLine(x.propertyX);

        dynamic y = Class1.CreateDynamic();
        Console.WriteLine(y.propertyX);
```

What do I need to do to make anonymous types work across dlls as dynamic types - or is that not possible?

**Update:** Fwiw, I figured out that I can get around that using ExpandoObjects, which I then 'cast' to dynamic, but ExpandoObjects are are not as nicely instantiable, when compared to the

```
new { key1 = val1, key2 = val2 }
```

style that anonymous types offer.

Comment: While you can't get instantiating expandos to be as clean as anonymous types, you can get close http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469224/expandoobject-anonymous-types-and-razor/7434036#7434036

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous types are internal to the assembly they are created in. If you have control over the source code you can make them [Friend Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx)

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("TheOtherAssembly")]
```

but there are [drawbacks](http://grabbagoft.blogspot.com/2007/10/double-edged-sword-of.html).

Comment: Awesome, that worked! Unfortunately, I can't wildcard "TheOtherAssembly" to allow any assembly to get access, and opening up the whole assembly seems a bit coarse grained... In any event, your answered explained why it doesn't work. Thanks!