# Deserialized JSON object to dynamic type but getting RuntimeBinderException accessing properties?

Tags: c#, dynamic, json.net, json-deserialization

I am using JSON.net in a C# Windows Form application to deserialize a JSON string to a dynamic object:

```
dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strJson);
```

I'm using the following test JSON for testing:

```
{"payload":"thePayload","number":3,"dialogResult":"one"}
```

When I run the code, I can indeed access the properties of the dynamic object using an associative array approach:

```
var x = jsonObj["payload"];
```

However, if I try to access the content using property names:

```
var x = jsonObj.payload;
```

It works but I get the following Exception:

```
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
```

Is there a way to change things so I can access the deserialized content in the dynamic object using property names instead of as an associative array, without getting the exception?

I found this SO post on RutimeBinderExceptions:

[Accessing properties of anonymous/dynamic types across dll boundaries gives RuntimeBinderException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656630/accessing-properties-of-anonymous-dynamic-types-across-dll-boundaries-gives-runt)

But I'd prefer not to use the ExpandoObject type and I'm not even sure if it applies to my situation.

UPDATE: Ok, I believe I am having the problem of depicted in the reference SO post above.  The context of the call is a callback from the CefSharp browser user control when Javascript calls back into my C# app.

Comment: Works well here, what version of Json.Net do you use? What if you use `JObject.Parse` ?

Comment: @Ofiris Same thing happens with JObject.Parse.  See my recent update to my post.  I believe it *is* related to the cross DLL boundaries issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try working without the `dynamic` data type:

```
Dictionary<string, object> theData= new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonString);

string payload = (string)theData["payload"];
int number = (int)theData["number"];
string dialogResult = (string)theData["dialogResult"];
```

The call to Deserialize() creates a tree of Dictionary that you can traverse at will.