# Problem with using a ToExpando method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hi I i try to use a ToExpando solution to use anonymous classes in razor views.
I use this solution -> [Dynamic Anonymous type in Razor causes RuntimeBinderException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120317/dynamic-anonymous-type-in-razor-causes-runtimebinderexception/5670899#5670899)

I'll write what i did:

1. I added a file Extensions.cs where i put following code:

   ```
   public static class Extensions
   {
       public static ExpandoObject ToExpando(this object anonymousObject)
       {
           IDictionary<string, object> anonymousDictionary = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(anonymousObject);
           IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();
           foreach (var item in anonymousDictionary)
               expando.Add(item);
           return (ExpandoObject)expando;
       }
   }
   ```
2. I wrote a query that receive a tuples from database in controller method:

   ```
   IEnumerable<dynamic> articles = (from p in db.Articles.Where(p => p.user_id == 2)
           select new
           {
               p.article_id,
               p.title,
               p.date,
               p.category,
               AverageScore = db.Articles_Scores
                   .Where(o => o.user_id == p.user_id && p.article_id == o.article_id)
                   .Average(m => m.score)
           }).AsEnumerable()
             .Select(r => r.ToExpando());
   int ii = 0;
   foreach(var it in articles) {
       // HERE I CAN READ EVERYTHING
       ii = it.article_id;
   }
   return View(articles);
   ```
3. In view I declare a model:

   ```
   @model IEnumerable<dynamic>
   ```
4. And I try to get every tuples:

   ```
   @foreach (dynamic item in Model) {
   // some code
       @item.article_id // HERE IS EXCEPTION
   }
   ```

In the foreach line I got an Exception:

**RuntimeBinderException**: *'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'article_id'*

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You've haven't shown is the code that actually calls `ToExpando`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot. Now I updated.

Answer (score 5):

You need to call `.AsEnumerable()` or `.ToList()` first to force `ToExpando` to run on the client.

Comment: Do you mean I should use ToExpando().AsEnumerable()? If so, I gave an similar exception :/

Comment: No; you need to call `AsEnumerable` _first_ so that `ToExpando` runs on the client

Comment: Ok. But I got an Exception: RuntimeBinderException: 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'article_id'

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
dynamic articles = (from p in db.Articles.Where(p => p.user_id == 2_
                select new
                {
                    p.article_id,
                    p.title,
                    p.date,
                    p.category,
                    AverageScore = db.Articles_Scores
                        .Where(o => o.user_id == p.user_id && p.article_id == o.article_id)
                        .Average(m => m.score)
                }).AsEnumerable()
                  .Select(r => r.ToExpando());
```

**Edit**: Make sure you declare `dynamic` not `var`

**Edit 2**: In your `for` look, you're declaring `var` again. Change it to:

```
@foreach (dynamic item in Model) {
    // some code
    @item.article_id // HERE IS EXCEPTION
}
```

Comment: I got an Exception: RuntimeBinderException: 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'article_id'

Comment: Thanks for help Matthew but it still doesnt work. I used IEnumerable<dynamic> and now I used your solution but still there is the same problem. It is strange... because it works perfect in controler method(foreach works great and I can read every properties) but in View(Razor) I got the same exception. I really dont know what i'm doing wrong...

Comment: I updated my post. Look at code below linq query. I also checked by comment a place where I got exception.

Comment: What worked for me is doing this ... (from ... (select new {}).ToExpando()).ToList().  Basically, making sure the expando was on the actual object created, not after.  Doing it the other way (With a new select) will also work, and may actually be cleaner looking.

Comment: Edit 1 is very important as the objects are created there. In my case Edit 2 was not required i.e. @foreach (var item in Model) worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Ok, building on the first two answers, I added another extension method that I'm surprised I don't see here:

```
public static List<ExpandoObject> ToExpandoList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> ie) {
    return ie.Select(o => o.ToExpando()).ToList();            
}
```

And now in my view I have code like this, and it works just fine using Razor.

```
var peoples = from f in "tom dick susan roberto".Split(' ') 
              select new { FirstName = f, Age = f.Length };
ViewBag.People = peoples.ToExpandoList();
```

Comment: linq.ToExpando().ToList() did not worked for me but your helper of .ToExpandoList() is successful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes()`, it's replacing 
'_' with '-' for the property name. Look at the comment for the method.