# Convert string value to object property name ASP.net MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, asp.net-mvc-4, object

is there any possibility to make object properties using String values in C# ?
like this :

```
object obj;
obj.makePropperty("username","user1");
obj.makePropperty("firstName","jnah");
obj.makePropperty("year",2014);

String getValue = obj.username;
```

Comment: Can't you use `Dictionary` for that?

Comment: Do you have any idea !

Comment: IDictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Foo", "Bar" } };
 dynamic dobj = dict.toexpando(); i can't find toexpando definition !

Comment: As far as I know there is no ToExpando method in the framework. This post talks about creating your own. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667273/problem-with-using-a-toexpando-method

Answer (score 2):

I think ExpandoObject was introduced in .NET 4.0. You could use that.

```
public dynamic MyObject { get; private set; }

MyObject = new ExpandoObject();

((IDictionary<string, object>)sourceObjectCustomFieldsExpando)Add(
    <PropertyName>, <Value> );
```

The only advantage of this over a dictionary that later on you can access the properties using dot notation.

```
((IDictionary<string, object>)MyObject)Add( "Foo", "bar" );

...

var value = MyObject.Foo;
```

Comment: I misunderstood that  can you explain it to me !

Comment: You'll have to be precise in your question. I already explained it in the original post. If you have a specific question I'd be happy to try to answer it.

Comment: What you suggest dosen't work for me @Craig because as i said i wannna create object properties based on String text like this : object obj;
obj.makePropperty("username","user1");
obj.makePropperty("firstName","jnah");
obj.makePropperty("year",2014);

Answer (score 1):

Using [anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx), you could create a new object like this:

```
var newObj = new { username = "user1", firstName = "jnah", year = "2014"};
```

Or if you had a class to represent your object looking like this:

```
public string username {get; set;}
public string firstName {get; set;}
public string year{get; set;}

var newObj = new myObj{ username = "user1", firstName = "jnah", year = "2014"};
```

**Update**: You could also use a list of Dictionary or KeyValuePairs:

```
var objList= new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("username ", "user1"));
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("firstName", "jnah"));
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("year", "2014"));
```

Comment: the issue is that i wanna create an object properties dynamically !

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood.  In that case as suggested by dkozl, use a [dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044482/setting-anonymous-type-property-name)

Comment: Could explain to me how to use iot please !!