# ViewBag and Unknown type using

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

```
var Urun = (from u in db.urunlers.Where(x => x.Yayinlama == "1")
                where u.UrunID == id
                select new
                {
                  u.UrunID,
                  UrunAdi= u.UrunAdi,
                  u.UrunAciklama,
                  u.YorumIzni
                }).SingleOrDefault();

    ViewBag.urun = Urun;
```

This is codebehind in my ".cs" page.

```
var Urun = ViewBag.urun;
<h3 class="Baslik"><%:Urun.UrunAdi %></h3>
```

This is my code ".aspx" page.

But i get 'object' does not contain a definition for 'UrunAdi' error?

---

I solved my problem via another method:

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

var Urun = (from u in db.urunlers.Where(x => x.Yayinlama == "1")
                    where u.UrunID == id
                    select new {
                      u.UrunAdi,
                      u.UrunID,
                      u.AltKategoriID,
                      Uretici=db.ureticilers.Where(x=>x.UreticiID==u.Uretici).Select(x=>x.UreticiAdi).FirstOrDefault()
                    }).SingleOrDefault();

        ViewBag.urun = js.Serialize(Urun);
```

And my aspx page code:

```
<%
var Urun = Json.Decode(ViewBag.urun);
%>
<h3 class="Baslik"><%:Urun.UrunAdi %></h3>
```

This method work very good :)
Thanks everyone..

Comment: Why you are assigning it **UrunAdi= u.UrunAdi,** Value. Can't you use only **u.UrunAdi,**?

Comment: ok i changed -select new{u.UrunID,u.UrunAdi}- but don't work :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['object' does not contain a definition for 'X'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652749/object-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-x)

Answer (score 2):

You are using an anonymous object here:

Please have a look to this Link

['object' does not contain a definition for 'X'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652749/object-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-x)