# How to return view with Outer Joins from two tables in MVC Razor

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've two tables as Models in my project Like:-

```
public partial class TblAlbum
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Album { get; set; }
    public string Artists { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AudioID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> VideoID { get; set; }

    public virtual TblVideo TblVideo { get; set; }
    public virtual TblAudio TblAudio { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public partial class TblAudio
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Alt { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public int LangID { get; set; }

    public virtual TblLanguage TblLanguage { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TblAlbum> TblAlbums { get; set; }
}
```

Now I've Made a ViewModel as **GetDetailsVM** that have access to both tables and has the ***LINQ Query*** as:-

```
public class GetDetailsVM
{
    private MusicEntities db = new MusicEntities();

    public IEnumerable<dynamic> GetAudio()
    {
        var AudioList = from au in db.TblAudios
                        join al in db.TblAlbums on au.ID equals al.AudioID into ar
                        from al in ar.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new { au,al };

        return AudioList.ToList();

    }
}
```

**My ViewModel(AudioAlbumVM) to read Getaudio() should be something like this:-**

```
public class AudioAlbumVM
{
    public IEnumerable<dynamic> AudioObjList { get; set; }
    public string AlbumName { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to access this ViewModel in my controller and then use it in my cshtml.

My Controller:-

```
public ActionResult Audio() 
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Audio";

    var AudioSummary = new GetDetailsVM();
    var viewModel = new AudioAlbumVM
    {
        AudioObjList = AudioSummary.GetAudio().First()
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

**UPDATE** 
My View(Audio.cshtml) is as follows:-

```
@model GarhwalMusic.Model‌​s.AudioAlbumVM.AudioObjList

 <a class="art" href="single.html"> @Model.AudioObjList</a>
```

I was going through this question [LINQ left join only works in the ActionResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049666/linq-left-join-only-works-in-the-actionresult) but I'm completely lost . Need help and explanation on how to **create AudioAlbumVM using another ViewModel(GetDetailsVM) then in controller and then in cshtml**. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: create a viewmodel with the properties that you need to use in view, and then populate the viewmodel from the result of GetAudio method

Comment: show the definition of ``AudioAlbumVM``class

Comment: In linq you need to select the required data into the `AudioAlbumVM` viewmodel.. So if you can provide details on that class we can help further

Comment: Thanks for your comments . I'm sorry wasn't able to format my question properly before. I've updated the question. There is my viewmodel AudioAlbumVM. Hope I can make myself clear this time.

Comment: @Deepak `IEnumerable<dynamic> AudioObjList` here what do you want to fill in place of `dynamic` ??

Comment: I want to get the result from getdetails.getaudio() and use them in my razor view as IEnumerable<>

Comment: @rajshekar Any Thoughts?

Comment: Now I'm getting this error:- The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'GarhwalMusic.Models.AudioAlbumVM', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[GarhwalMusic.Models.AudioAlbumVM]'.

Answer (score 0):

Taking this from your comments

> Now I'm getting this error:- The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'GarhwalMusic.Models.AudioAlbumVM', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[GarhwalMusic.Model‌​s.AudioAlbumVM]'.

Problem is with this code

```
    var viewModel = new AudioAlbumVM //its a single model
    {
        AudioObjList = AudioSummary.GetAudio().First()
    };
```

But it seems like your view is expecting a `model` of type `IEnumerable<GarhwalMusic.Model‌​s.AudioAlbumVM>` or (`List<GarhwalMusic.Model‌​s.AudioAlbumVM>`). You need to either pass a `List<GarhwalMusic.Model‌​s.AudioAlbumVM>` to your view or change your view to accept a model of type `GarhwalMusic.Model‌​s.AudioAlbumVM`.

But looking at your code I assume that you are trying to pass the collection of `AudioObjList` into your View. So your view must accept a model of type

`GarhwalMusic.Model‌​s.AudioAlbumVM.AudioObjList` and you need to just Pass in only the `viewModel.AudioObjList` from your controller.

**EDIT 1:** After you added more details of your view, You are making a mistake in the way you are accessing the data.

your `Model.AudioObjList` is of type `IEnumerable<dynamic>` and how can you just print something on the Vie like `@Model.AudioObjList` ?? I am referring to this code

```
<a class="art" href="single.html"> @Model.AudioObjList</a>
```

You need to typecast this dynamic type into what ever object you have created in your linq and then extract its property value. Something like

```
@((yourObject)Model.AudioObjList[0]).propertyName
```

`(yourObject)Model.AudioObjList[0]` type casts your `dynamic` data into a type `yourObject`.

you need `[0]` because your `AudioObjList` is of type `IEnumerable<dynamic>`. So taking the first data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my controller I changed return View(viewModel); to return View(viewModel.AudioObjList); and my view now accept @model GarhwalMusic.Model‌​s.AudioAlbumVM.AudioObjList. But I'm getting this error now:- Cannot implicitly convert type '<>f__AnonymousType2<GarhwalMusic.Models.TblAudio,GarhwalMusic.Models.TblAlbum>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>'

Comment: @Deepak to see the reason you might have to post your view code and part where you get this error at..

Comment: I'm sorry I'm like learning MVC right now so some concepts are new to me. Here I can't figure out how to fill 'yourObject' in @((yourObject)Model.AudioObjList[0]).propertyName. And how can I access it? PS: It seems I'm never gonna solve this. :(

Comment: I tried to make a list object as well :- @{
                                    List<GarhwalMusic.Models.AudioAlbumVM> AAVM= ((au)Model.AudioObjList[0]).Album as List<GarhwalMusic.Models.AudioAlbumVM>;
                                }

                                @foreach(var item in AAVM)
                                {
                                    @item.AudioObjList
                                } Here 'au' is selected in linq in Model GetDetailsVM.

Comment: I've highlighted it in my question above also.  var AudioList = from au in db.TblAudios
                        join al in db.TblAlbums on au.ID equals al.AudioID into ar
                        from al in ar.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new { au,al };

Comment: @Deepak I would suggest you to remove `dynamic` object type and have a defined class instead. like `public IEnumerable<yourNewObject> AudioObjList { get; set; }` then in your linq you can extract values into specific type on `select` clause.