# What is error when my query has an anonymous object and iteration on this in HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is error when my query has an anonymous object and iteration on this in HTML page by model `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''object' does not contain a definition for 'st''`

Comment: Hi, we need to see more details like your code. First thought for me it's you are using anonymous object. You might want to convert it to view model. Please check this link for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652749/object-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-x

Comment: [This link can help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652749/object-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-x) If not, add the code part to your item.

Comment: how can display the result of query in html page @Kadir