# "Group by" using LINQ and dynamic anonimous type

Tags: linq

I´m writing an ASP .NET MVC web site and i´m with a LINQ problem. I have a simple class

```
public class Tag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    ... [other props]....

}
```

And i want to pass to the view a list of grouped Nomes. I tried to the following LINQ code to generate a list

```
var teste = (from t in db.Tags
                    group t by t.Nome into g
                    select new
                    {
                        Nome = g.Key
                    }).ToList();
ViewBag.ListaTags = teste;
```

and it´s ok, but if i use the following code in the View

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.ListaTags)
{
     @item.Nome
}
```

I got an error message saying that the object item has no Nome property. If i try @item instead of @item.Nome, it display {Nome = "Test"}. It´s like I have an object but I can´t access it´s properties.

Comment: Have you tried `@item["Nome']`?

Comment: Yes, i tried. Don´t work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look this Marc's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930102/retrieve-property-from-a-dynamic-object-after-storing-retrieving-it-from-the-ses). Instead of returning a anonymous type, you can decalre a POCO class and return that object like this:-

```
var teste = (from t in db.Tags
                         group t by t.Nome into g
                         select new Nome
                         {
                             groupedNome = g.Key
                         }).ToList();
```

POCO class I have used here is:-

```
public class Nome
{
     public string groupedNome { get; set; }
}
```

Then , you can use this in `View` as:-

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.ListaTags)
{
     @item.groupedNome
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After Grouping you are having structure of Grouped data in format like::

```
Group.key1=> [value1,value2,value3],
Group.key2=> [value1,value2,value3],
Group.key3=> [value1,value2,value3]
```

And if you want to show something grouped then you should select Grouped values also with its Key as::

```
var teste = (from t in db.Tags
                    group t by t.Nome into g
                    select new
                    {
                        Nome = g.Key,
                        Id=g
                    }).ToList();
```

Then you can show it on client side as::

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.ListaTags)
{
    <p>@item.Key  </p>
    foreach (var subitem in item.Values)
    {
        @subitem    
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Rahul. I got an error message, something linke "Object does not contains a definition for Key (and for Values). Thank you!