# MVC3: How to link view form HTML UI with different ID to one controller/Model

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, submit

At first - sorry for my broken English. May be it is stupid question, but....
So, I have a model

```
public class AAAModel {
  public int I1 {get; set}
  public string S1 ...
  public Guid G1 ...
}
```

I have a controller

```
public ActionResult Create(AAAModel WhatToCreate){
  ...
}
```

And I have a proper view to enter the data... All was fine, but now I must reorganize view to create several form and give the user ability to dynamically create new objects (model) and send query to the server. The data, that I got from server cames as Ajax query and parsed to the table grid... User may view this data, correct it and may send it back.
So, I make several forms wich I duplicate from initial view and change the ID and Name of the controls
Originally it was like

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.I1)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.S1)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.G1)
```

And now it bacame like

```
<input id="I1_1" name="I1_1 ...>
<input id="S1_1" name="S1_1 ...>
<input id="G1_1" name="G1_1 ...>
```

in form 1;

```
<input id="I1_2" name="I1_2 ...>
<input id="S1_2" name="S1_2 ...>
<input id="G1_2" name="G1_2 ...>
```

in form 2, and so on...
Stupid question, but how can I modify the controller or what I have to do to got these values?

P.S. These forms will send via ajax... and host-page will not reload.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/ and here: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

**UPDATE**

You can always use [FormCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection(v=vs.108).aspx) to get the passed model values.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(FormCollection values) 
{
   string I1_2 = values["I1_2"];    
   //do something
}
```

If you need you can work with dynamic objects specifying `@model dynamic` but you don't need to as the default for views is to derive from `WebViewPage<dynamic>`.

Also look here if you need to pass the anonymous object
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5670899/1241400

Comment: Thanks. I think about these methods. Worst that in my case I has no list. The user must submit only one form at a time, but wich one - we don't know. And we can't make the same "name" attribute inside input elements - the unobtrusive validations will broke otherwise.  :( I start thinking that global redesign of the page is needed...

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if under stand your question correctly. And sure if your are doing this and its not working but why not just simply create multiple forms on the page . So when the user submits a certain form it will only submit the inputs in that form.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Method","Controller",FormMethod.Post,new {id="form1"}))
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.I1)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.S1)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.G1)
  <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id=form1Submit />
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Method","Controller",FormMethod.Post,new {id="form2"}))
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.I1)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.S1)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.G1)
  <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id=form2Submit />
}
...
```

of course you are going to create this dynamically. 
I am sorry if i am just repeating your question

**EDIT**

If your issue is how to determine what set of data was submitted I would add an id field to the model and change it for every new form you create

Comment: In the simplest way the Submit of one of the form will reload all the page... And one more: does the validation will work on these forms?

Comment: you can make these Ajax forms ... `@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Home", new AjaxOptions{...}` as for validation i have never done this my self but i would asume it would work.