# TemplateService.Parse gives "Invalid token for impersonation - it cannot be duplicated" when using anonymous model and cache name

Tags: c#, razor, razorengine

I have followed [this tutorial](http://mehdi.me/generating-html-emails-with-razorengine-introduction/) to use the RazorEngine to generate HTML emails (without ASP.NET MVC). It worked fine when I used either a strongly typed view or an anonymous object as the model:

**Layout.cshtml**

```
@model dynamic
// html contents...
```

**C# snippet**

```
var template = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Properties.Resources.ContractList);

var model = new
{
    ContractList = list
};

var templateService = new TemplateService();
var html = templateService.Parse(template, model, null, null);
```

Then I gave it a cache name, as recommended on the [third part of the tutorial](http://mehdi.me/generating-html-emails-with-razorengine-part-03-caching-vs-integration-namespace-config/):

```
templateService.Parse(template, model, null, nameof(Properties.Resources.ContractList));
```

It worked fine with the strongly typed object, but with the anonymous object I started receiving this message as of the second time it ran:

> Invalid token for impersonation - it cannot be duplicated

How can I resolve this and still use an anonymous object for the model?

I have seen solutions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737760/razorengine-using-anonymous-objects-runtimebinderexception), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612938/razor-view-with-anonymous-type-model-class-it-is-possible#6613040)) that suggest transforming the anonymous object to an `ExpandoObject`, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the RazorEngine docs, I found some examples on their [upgrading page](https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/Upgrading.html#Code-examples) which showed how to use `Engine.Razor`. The easiest way to do it is:

```
var html = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(
    template,
    nameof(Properties.Resources.ContractList),
    null,
    model
);
```

This solved the issue. Just beware that they don't recommend the above format, because internally it will call `AddTemplate` every time, and that it will throw an exception when you use the same `cache_name` for different templates. Instead they recommend precompiling on startup:

```
// Once at startup (not required when using an ITemplateManager which knows how to
// resolve cache_name)
Engine.Razor.AddTemplate(cache_name, razorTemplate)
// On startup
Engine.Razor.Compile(
    cache_name, 
    typeof(MyModel) /* or model.GetType() or null for 'dynamic'*/
)

// instead of the Razor.Parse call
var result = Engine.Razor.Run(
    cache_name,
    typeof(MyModel), /* or model.GetType() or null for 'dynamic'*/
    model
)
```