# Linq call using anonymous/dynamic type does work in view

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

For the life of me I cannot figure out why this works. I'm simply calling some data via link and passing it on to the view. It works when I passe the data directly like this:

```
var invoices = (
  from s in navdb.Sales_Invoice_Header
  where s.Salesperson_Code == repCode
  where s.Posting_Date > date
  select s
).ToList();
```

But when I create an anonymous type on the fly it does not, like this:

```
var invoices = (
  from s in navdb.Sales_Invoice_Header
  where s.Salesperson_Code == repCode
  where s.Posting_Date > date
  select new { 
    s.No_,
    s.Bill_to_Customer_No_,
    s.Bill_to_Name,
    s.Salesperson_Code
  }
).ToList();
```

when accessing it like this after:

```
<table>
@foreach (var invoice in ViewBag.invoices)
{ 
<tr>
    <td>@invoice.No_</td>
    <td>@invoice.Bill_to_Customer_No_</td>
    <td>@invoice.Bill_to_Name</td>
    <td>@invoice.Salesperson_Code</td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

I just get an: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'No_'

I've tried adding No_ = s.No_ and so forth, that does not help either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate question here: [Dynamic Anonymous type in Razor causes RuntimeBinderException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120317/dynamic-anonymous-type-in-razor-causes-runtimebinderexception)

> The reason for this is that the anonymous type being passed in the
>   controller in internal, so it can only be accessed from within the
>   assembly in which it’s declared. Since views get compiled separately,
>   the dynamic binder complains that it can’t go over that assembly
>   boundary.

Basically, you can't bind against anonymous dynamic objects in this way. Define a specific class or struct to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you're getting a `List<whatever s is>`, in your second example, you're getting a `List<object>`. And `'object' does not contain a definition for 'No_'`