# RuntimeBinderException when accessing dynamic anonymous type in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic, anonymous-types

I've encountered a strange anomaly while learning/tinkering with asp.net.

I'm trying to show a partial view like this:

```
@Html.Partial("_PartialView", new { Action = "Foo" })
```

When I'm trying to access Action with

```
// Throws Microsoft.Csharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException
string throwsException = Model.Action;
```

a RuntimeBinderExceptionis with the message

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Action'

is thrown.
The strange thing is that this line works fine:

```
// This line works fine
string works = ((Type)Model.GetType()).GetProperty("Action").GetValue(Model);
```

This behavior puzzles me quite a bit and I'd rather avoid using this workaround. Also I don't think the problem is [anonymous types being internal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120317/dynamic-anonymous-type-in-razor-causes-runtimebinderexception) because the MVC template for ASP.NET Project in VS2013 does this successfully:

[image]

So what happened here?

Comment: This happened to me; it was working - and then it just stopped, for no good reason. I cannot figure out why. Like you mention in another comment: weakly typed views with anonymous types *do* work in other places, such as the Visual Studio templates. The question is what makes them suddenly stop working here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So what happened here?

Your partial view is weakly typed. You do not have a `@model` definition for it. So by default it is `object` which obviously doesn't have an `Action` property.

The correct way to solve this is to define a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

that your partial view will be strongly typed to:

```
@model MyViewModel
@{
    string throwsException = Model.Action; 
}
```

and which will be passed by the main view:

```
@Html.Partial("_PartialView", new MyViewModel { Action = "Foo" })
```

Another possibility (which personally I don't like as it relies on runtime binding) is to use a dynamic model in the partial view:

```
@model dynamic
@{
    string throwsException = Model.Action; 
}
```

and then you will be able to pass an anonymous object when calling it:

```
@Html.Partial("_PartialView", new { Action = "Foo" })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Creating a view model does solve this issue (dynamic model did not; Model is already dynamic). I'll accept this answer in a few days if it's still the best/only answer until then. But one thing still bothers me: Why does the MVC template for ASP.NET Project in VS2013 work? Its partial view is also weakly typed. In fact my partial view is just a tweaked version of it. If you can add an explanation to your answer I'll accept it right away.

Comment: While using a VM avoids/solves the problem, it does not explain the error. The default case normally accepts dynamic/anonymous objects (not Object). Anonymous types normally work in partial views, but under some (as-yet unknown circumstance) it simply stops working. I have just hit this same problem and have had to change it to use strongly typed objects. As Kabbalah says, `@model dynamic` fails the same way as the original (as it is already expecting a dynamic).

Comment: You could also use reflection but that would be the wrong thing to do. You could add an extension method on Object with T GetData<T>(this object model,String key)... return model.GetType().GetProperty(key).GetValue(model) as T. As a static utility method it would be better. Let's be honest the performance hit isn't that bad. Helper.Data<T>(Model, key).

Answer (score 10):

The answer to this question can be found here: http://www.heartysoft.com/ashic/blog/2010/5/anonymous-types-c-sharp-4-dynamic

Pulling from the excellent blog post:

`Anonymous Types are Internal`

The reason the call to `Model.Action` fails is that the type information of `Model` is not available at runtime. The reason it's not available is because anonymous types are not public. When the method is returning an instance of that anonymous type, it's returning a System.Object which references an instance of an anonymous type -  a type who's info isn't available to the main program. The dynamic runtime tries to find a property called `Action` on the object, but can't resolve it from the type information it has. As such, it throws an exception.

Comment: Why does the VS2013 MVC template work then? See the screenshot in my question.

Comment: Not anymore it can't

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options using reflection. The performance should be negligible in most scenarios.

**Utility Class**

```
public static class ModelHelper
{
    public static T Data<T>( String key)  
    {
        var html = ((System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage)WebPageContext.Current.Page).Html;
        var model = html.ViewData.Model;
        return (T)model.GetType().GetProperty(key).GetValue(model) ;
    }
}
```

**view.cshtml**

```
@(Html.Partial("partial",new { Id="InstructorId"}))
```

**paritial.cshtml file**

```
@model dynamic 
@{ 
    var id = ModelHelper.Data<String>("Id");
}
```

**With a more compact parital call in view.cshtml**

```
@{
  var instructorId = "InstructorId";
  var windowTitle = "Window Title";
  var editorPageUrl = "~/View/Editors/Instructors.chstml";
}

@(Html.Partial("partial",new { instructorId, windowTitle, editorPageUrl }))
```

**With variables adjusted to get inferred names in paritial.cshtml file**

```
@model dynamic 
@{ 
    var id = ModelHelper.Data<String>("instructorId");
    var id = ModelHelper.Data<String>("windowTitle");
    var id = ModelHelper.Data<String>("editorPageUrl");
}
```

It is not hard to create a simple view-model class but I don't like classes that will only ever be used a single time for passing data, so this works for me.

**You could also extend the default view base**

```
namespace SafetyPlus.Shell.Code
{
    public abstract class ExtendedPageBaseClass<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel> where TModel : class
    {
        public T Data<T>(String key) 
        {
            return (T)Model.GetType().GetProperty(key).GetValue(Model);
        }

        public Object Data(String key) 
        {
            return Data<Object>(key);
        }
    }
}
```

**Register the base class in the /Views/web.config**

```
<pages pageBaseType="SafetyPlus.Shell.Code.ExtendedPageBaseClass">
  ...
</pages>
```

**Get the data in your partial view like this**

```
@{ 
    var id = Data("Id");
    var idTyped = Data<String>("Id");
}
```

**Or using an extension method which I suggested against.**

```
namespace NotYourDefaultNamespace
{
    public static class ModelExtensions
    {
        public static T Data<T>( this Object model, String key)  
        {
            return (T)model.GetType().GetProperty(key).GetValue(model) ;
        }
    }
}
```

This options really doesn't buy you anything since we are finding the model from within the previous utility method. The call would become.

```
@{
    var id = Model.Data("Id");
}
```