# Pass dynamic types to RazorEngine

Tags: c#, razor, razorengine

I'm using RazorEngine to render and parse some cshtml programmatically (and get html).
I need to pass programmatically some data (a list of object) to a template and use these objects inside this template.

How to pass these data and how to use them inside my template, and then parse it?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicates. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120317/dynamic-anonymous-type-in-razor-causes-runtimebinderexception

Comment: @Clamidity: the problem is that I have no idea.
At the moment I'm doing so to parse the template:
 result = Razor.Parse(cshtmlTemplate, view);
Where cshtmlTemplate is the template cshtml in which I wanto to pass my IMyObject list of object

Comment: Have you tried something like this: result = Razor.Parse(cshtmlTemplate, myObject); with the following at the top of the cshtmlTemplate: @model Namespace.For.IMyObject?

Comment: @Clamidity: and what about my view object that contains my data? I need a further object that is different from the view I'm already passing

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast the objects going into the template.

**ViewData is used to pass data from controller to corresponding view.**

[ViewData vs ViewBag vs TempData vs Session](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/9KHW190712-ViewData-vs-ViewBag-vs-TempData-vs-Session.html)

There is also a [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yq1N7zfZTBo).

Comment: I see, but how to pass the object into the template "scope"?

Comment: Do you mean like using ViewBag?

Comment: I don't know, probably :) what is the viewbag? How to use it?