# How can I show group data in asp.mvc views?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have this linq query

```
var impuestos = conceptos
    .GroupBy(a => a.ImpuestoId)
    .Select(a => new
    {
        id = a.Key,
        montoImpuesto = a.Sum(b => b.montoImpuesto), 
        impuestoNombre = a.FirstOrDefault().impuesto.Nombre,
        impuestoTipo = a.FirstOrDefault().impuesto.Tipo,
    })
    .ToList();

ViewBag.grupo = impuestos;
```

And I want to show it in a view. It tried this

```
@foreach (var impuesto in ViewBag.grupo)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @impuesto.id
        </td>
        <td>
            @impuesto.Nombre
        </td>
        <td>
            @impuesto.montoImpuesto
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

But I get an error telling there is no definition for 'id' in the object. I already tried adding a foreach inside the main foreach, but I get different errors. What is the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

An object once added to `ViewBag` gets converted to type `object` (boxed). You will have to unbox it to specific type before using. The select query returns an anonymous object, instead create a entity class, which is used to return grouped collection. Convert `ViewBag.grupo` to `IEnumerable<T>` on the View and then use it in the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use anonymous objects as models (well, you can, but they're passed as `object` and you can't cast them to the original type, since it's anonymous!). Either create a model class, or use a [hack like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120317/dynamic-anonymous-type-in-razor-causes-runtimebinderexception/5670899#5670899).