# How HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes works behind the scenes? (Method calls itself)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection

I did a reflection with ILSpy of System.Web.MVC.dll and found out the following code:

```
public static RouteValueDictionary AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    }
```

Can someone help me to understand what exactly is happening here? This should lead to a StackOverflow Exception, but doesn't.

Comment: What makes you think it would throw a `StackOverflowException`? The method is calling the `AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes()` method of the `HtmlHelper` class

Comment: @Stephen Muecke It's calling itself.

Comment: Where? This is the [source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/HtmlHelper.cs) for `HtmlHelper`. The method you have shown is not code in the `HtmlHelper` class. Its in another class which is calling the `AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes)` static method of `HtmlHelper`. They just happen to have the same name.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Stephen Muecke commented above, the method AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes from System.Web.MVC.HtmlHelper is calling a method with the same name but from System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper.

The ILSpy is not explicitly about that. I needed to hover the class to show from where it was coming:

[image: ILSpy]

I'm not the first with that [doubt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31370765/ilspy-a-k-a-net-reflector-shows-a-method-as-just-calling-itself-why), it's a common mistake to be made, I believe.