# How to access data from query without a model in ASP.NET 5 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to execute a query inside a controller using EF7 and to display data in a table.

Here are my models:

```
public class Resources
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string descr { get; set; }
    public string resourcePath { get; set; }
    public string method { get; set; }
    public string format { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MeasureTags> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class MeasureSets
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string descr { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public bool isPublic { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MeasureTags> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class MeasureTags
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public bool isPublic { get; set; }
    public int sortOrder { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MeasureSets")]
    public int msId { get; set; }
    public virtual MeasureSets ms { get; set; }

    public virtual Resources res { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the join query in the controller:

```
//get users measure sets
var m_sets = from t in _context.MeasureTags
             join s in _context.MeasureSets on t.ms.id equals s.id 
             where s.userName == User.Identity.Name
             select new {
                 id = t.id,
                 set = s.name,
                 tag = t.name,
                 res = t.res.name
             };

return View(m_sets.ToArray());
```

In the view I have a foreach loop that is able to extract correctly each row but not the columns. Error: **'object' does not contain a definition for 'id' (item.id)**

```
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   string tagid = "tag" + item.id;
       <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" checked id="@tagid"/></td>
        <td>@item.set</td>
        <td>@item.tag</td>
        <td>@item.res</td>
       </tr>
    }
}
</tbody>
```

I added also an extra model for the result but still without success. Error is **'ManageTagTableModel' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'**

```
public class TagTable
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string set { get; set; }
    public string tag { get; set; }
    public string res { get; set; }
}

public class ManageTagTableModel : IEnumerable
{
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable)TagTable).GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

The question is: how can I access the 'new' generic object properties if possible without the need for additional models?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/5670899/1808494

Comment: Thanks to Stephen Muecke I was able to make this run.
But I am still wandering if there is an option to acces properties of a generic object without a model..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to project your query into new instances of `TagTable`

```
var m_sets = from t in _context.MeasureTags
             join s in _context.MeasureSets on t.ms.id equals s.id 
             where s.userName == User.Identity.Name
             select new TagTable {
                 id = t.id,
                 set = s.name,
                 tag = t.name,
                 res = t.res.name
             };
return View(m_sets.ToArray());
```

and then in the view

```
@model IEnumerable<TagTable>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.set</td>
        ....
```