# Foreach from IQueryable

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

This is in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        var groupJoin = from d in db.tblParent1
                        join e in db.tblParent2 on d.parent1ID equals e.parent1ID
                        select new
                        {
                            parent1ID = d.parent1ID,
                            parent1Name = d.parent1Name,
                            parent2ID = e.parent2ID,
                            parent2Name = e.parent2Name,
                        };
        ViewBag.groupJoin = groupJoin.ToList();
        return View();
}
```

This is my view:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.groupJoin)
{
    <tr>
         <td>
                @item.parent1Name
         </td>
         <td>
                @item.parent2Name
         </td>
   </tr>
}
```

I get this error :

> object does not contain a definition for `parent1Name`

when replacing `@item.parent1Name` with `@item`. It displays the whole row like this in the web

```
{ parent1ID = 1, parent1Name = master , parent2ID = 2, parent2Name = child }
```

How can I specify a column?

Comment: You are not applying foreach on IQueryable, Its List.

Comment: Maybe, because your result object is anonymous, the poroperties is not recognizable, try use a predifined type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic Anonymous type in Razor causes RuntimeBinderException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120317/dynamic-anonymous-type-in-razor-causes-runtimebinderexception)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a class like this

```
public class Result
{
   public int parent1ID    { get; set; }
   public string parent1Name  { get; set; }
   public int parent2ID    { get; set; }
   public string parent2Name  { get; set; }
}
```

And do the following

```
var groupJoin = from d in db.tblParent1
                    join e in db.tblParent2 on d.parent1ID 
equals e.parent1ID
                    select new Result
                    {
                        parent1ID = d.parent1ID,
                        parent1Name = d.parent1Name,
                        parent2ID = e.parent2ID,
                        parent2Name = e.parent2Name,
                    };
```