# 'object' does not contain a definition for <property> in asp.net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, partial-views, expandoobject, anonymous-objects

there are two parts to this question

number 1: 
im having receiving the same issue as in this post
the only diff is that im running in asp.net core v3.1
[Dynamic Anonymous type in Razor causes RuntimeBinderException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120317/dynamic-anonymous-type-in-razor-causes-runtimebinderexception/5670899#5670899)

ive tried the expando solution
but i still get the 'object' does not contain a definition for 'myproperty' err

heres my code
in **controller**:

```
        var obj = new { newRoundNumber = maxround + 1 };
        IDictionary<string, object> dict = new ExpandoObject();
        dict.Add("p", obj);
        var expando = StaticFunctions.ToExpando(dict);
        return PartialView("_RoundsPartial", expando);
```

in **partialview**:

```
@{
var p =  Model.p;
var newRound = p.newRoundNumber;   <--- fails

for (var r = 1; r <= newRound; r++)
{
    <div>@r</div>
}
```

}

can someone tell me whats up?

number 2:
apparently this used to work

```
new{
  Project = projectInfo,
  WorkItem = workitem
}.ToExpando());
```

but no longer in asp.net core v3.1
the conversion it allows is ToString()
does anyone know the equivalent in asp.net core?

UPDATE:
there was a comment response to try this link:
https://sebnilsson.com/blog/convert-c-anonymous-or-any-types-into-dynamic-expandoobject/

in short:

```
using System.Dynamic;
public static ExpandoObject ToExpandoObject(this object obj)
{
    IDictionary expando = new ExpandoObject();

    foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in 
        TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj.GetType()))
    {
        expando.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(obj));
    }

    return (ExpandoObject) expando;
}
```

currently this returns in error on this line:

```
    IDictionary expando = new ExpandoObject();
```

with: 
cannot implicitly convert type ExpandoObject to IDictionary

and vice versa with the return

Comment: https://sebnilsson.com/blog/convert-c-anonymous-or-any-types-into-dynamic-expandoobject/

Comment: @TimWilliams thx for replying - yes i saw that blog and tried it - it didnt work - i will note in post

Answer (score 0):

```
var expando = StaticFunctions.ToExpando(dict);
return PartialView("_RoundsPartial", dict);
```

Did you mean to pass in `expando` and not `dict`?

The extension method worked for me:

```
public static System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject ToExpandoObject(this object obj)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj.GetType()))
    {
        expando.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(obj));
    }
    return (ExpandoObject)expando;
}
```

...but I got the same error "object does not contain a definition"

Comment: oh yes @tim i meant to pass expando to the PV but i was running the code and it kept crashing out so i bypassed it - i will amend the OP - thanks!

Comment: about the extension method working for you - weird... i will retry - thank you tim.  PS i feel like im the onlyl person in the world that cant convert an IDict to expando since every article i read seems to be doing it...

Comment: Note the code above is slightly different from the code in the link I added -  `IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();` vs,.  `IDictionary expando = new ExpandoObject();` in the link.